# I can't login into my sendgrid account with Heroku's Username and password

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I had deployed my Rails project through Heroku.
Recently, I decided to add mailer to that app and deployed the master branch.
In order to send a email, I installed SendGrid add-on and followed the document which you can find in dev center.
I set up SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD. After that I tried to login but it didn't accept them.
I don't quite understand what is happening here.
If someone is experiencing same situation, please enlighten me how to solve this probrem.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Questions about the Heroku platform fall within our scope here, but I think this question is best directed to SendGrid support as their addon and product isn't part of the Salesforce product suite.

Answer (score 0):

Is this related to `SendGrid` addon available on Heroku? And you are trying to login to SendGrid via UserName and Password? If yes, then that wont work.

Heroku Addons are logged in via SSO. So as soon as you install a addon its visible on your apps `resources` tab.

[image]

You can just click the `SendGrid` label and SSO will take care of logging you in to `SendGrid`